# TRP HY-RD brake pistons won't retract to take new pads

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-pads

I'm replacing pads on my TRP Hy-Rd brakes. These are cable actuated hydraulics. Using tire levers, wrenches, etc. I have not been able to push the two pistons far enough apart to fit the rotor between the pads. I can move one piston, but the other follows, so there's no increase in the gap. I've tried pushing the pistons apart both with and without the old pads in place. Not having any luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detaching the cable reduced the pressure and allowed the pistons to both slide back.

Comment: Accept your own answer to mark the problem as solved.

Comment: For future readers - I think what was happening here was that the actuating lever was pulled slightly which cuts the main cylinders off from the reservoir. If fluid is prevented from flowing into the reservoir the pistons cannot be retracted.