# TRP Hy/Rd callipers rubbing

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I’ve just installed a set of TRP HY/RD brakes and I can’t seem to stop the front ones from rubbing the rotor. I’ve tried realigning the calliper but it seems to be rubbing on both sides not just one. I’ve checked the lock knob and it will thread into the actuator arm and I believe the arm is fully retracting. How do I get the pads a little wider whilst fully retracted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your disc is not warped. Is the disc rubbing the left inboard and outboard pad at different points of the wheel's revolution? If yes, you likely have a warped rotor. Look straight down through the caliper with a bright light and a sheet of white paper held behind it to see when the rotor is hitting the pads.

Is the gap between the pads just tight? The pistons may be extended from the caliper a little. Remove the pads and try pushing the pistons fully back into the caliper.

FYI be aware of advice in [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/56625/24228) about adjusting HYRD calipers.

Comment: Thanks, I’m guessing I need to extend the pistons a little. I’ll give that a go after reading all the advice linked 

Comment: @MarkRobinson retract the pistons, not extend them

Comment: I took the pads out and pushed the pistons in then replaced the pads. That wasn’t enough though as it turned out the stays for the mud guard were pressing against the brakes pushing them in a little. Once I bent them out of the way the rotor sailed through the callipers without touching 